# how to give directory path obove one directory in phalcon php

Tags: php, phalcon

I am new to phalcon php,
I want to give path one directory obove using 'use'
for ex, I am having two directories
example1/
example2/

one class is there in example1/example1.php

I want to access example2/example2.php in example1.php

How can I specify that using use??

I tried 
use example2/example2
use example2/example2.php 
but both not working.

Answer (score 0):

you need to up one directory try

`use ../example2/example2`

although I'd recommend using namespacing instead to keep you application clean